# How to decompile pyc to py on Python 3.9?

Tags: python, pyc

I want to decompile PYC file in Python 3.9. I tried decompyle3, uncompyle6, but output was like this:

```
Error: decompyle3 requires Python 3.7-3.8
```

What I should use?

Comment: downgrade to py3.8, wait for Rocky to release a version supporting 3.9, or fix the problem and submit a PR... your choice.  (ps: https://github.com/rocky/python-decompile3/blob/47b5587b0a18b9fa7bea901a3694b56cb9c7f073/decompyle3/bin/decompile.py#L73)

Comment: It isn't a solution

Comment: maybe not, but they are your 3 options (I'm guessing paying someone else to do it is out of the question...)

Comment: If you really have to support 3.9, you're going to have to do it yourself.  Change the line which requires 3.7-8, have a go, and fix it where it starts breaking (and do submit a PR when you're done).  The changes between 3.8 and 3.9 are not enormous, so it likely won't be too much work.  If the code you're trying to decompile is <3.9 anyway, you won't have to implement 3.9isms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have to support 3.9, you're going to have to do it yourself.

Clone the repo locally, Change [the line which requires 3.7-8](https://github.com/rocky/python-decompile3/blob/47b5587b0a18b9fa7bea901a3694b56cb9c7f073/decompyle3/bin/decompile.py#L73), have a go, and fix it where it starts breaking (and do submit a PR when you're done). The changes between 3.8 and 3.9 are not enormous, so it likely won't be too much work. If the code you're trying to decompile is <3.9 anyway, you won't actually have to implement 3.9isms, so it may run straight off---code *written* in 3.8 will likely run in 3.9, as AFAIK the APIs haven't changed noticeable.  I haven't looked at how compiling works, though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: The operative part of this answer is "I haven't looked at how compiling works". I suggest looking at it in more detail, and revise the above with a more informed answer. Between 3.8 and 3.9 opcodes have changed. A more informed answer would look at those changes understand how they are used in compiling and how the existing decompilers work.

Comment: @rocky that is very fair: if you're the Rocky behind decomplye3 I apologies for any spam this answer may have caused.  It was merely a comment saying 'well if you really need that, go and try to implement it' which became an answer at the OP's express request.  I hate seeing unanswered qs, so, as this apparently solved the OP's problem, I posted it as an answer.